# CentOS 5.8 dependencies on Python 2.4?

Tags: python, centos

I have a CentOS 5.8 server and am planning to install a later version of python (presumably 2.7). I have heard a lot of mention that CentOS relies quite heavily on 2.4 for many admin features etc. I'm trying to determine exactly what these features are (and whether I would actually be using them) so that I can decide whether to update python through yum or build from source.

Can anyone give me some more detailed information on what CentOS features have dependencies on Python 2.4.

Comment: Ahh, the yum package manager itself is dependent on 2.4

Comment: It does depend on 2.4. Don't uninstall it. But multiple versions of Python can be installed at the saem time. I have RPMs for it: ftp://ftp.pycopia.org/pub/python/centos/5/i386/

Comment: BTW, this is not a programming question. You should move it to superuser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If python2.7 is available on  Yum, you should use that: the package management on large distros (redhat, ubuntu, debian, fedora ) takes care of maintaining parallel Python installs for you which won't conflict with each other.

This option should keep your system "/usr/bin/python¬ file pointing to Python2.4 and give you another python2.7 binary.

Otherwise, if you choose to build it from source, pick another prefix - /opt - (not even /usr/local will be quite safe) for building it.

You don't need to know exactly which system parts depend on Python 2.4 - just rest assured it will crash very hard and unpredictably if you try to modify the system Python itself.

Comment: Is it possible to force my Trac installation on CentOS 5 to use newer Python (2.5 at least) while everything else would stay on Py 2.4?

Comment: yes, seetinng proper enviroment variable,s or better yet, using virtualenv - for a better answer, you could possibly paste this as a question to superuser.com